# downvoting random comments in answers?

Tags: support, answers, downvoting

I saw some answers where the user just puts in random comment. I like what I read from this link "
http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1305/flag-answers-that-should-be-comments " but is downvoting  these comments a useful thing to do as well?

one example of such a comment is https://askubuntu.com/a/94223/24314 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a useful deterrent as it costs the poster some reputation but it also costs you reputation.

I think you'd be better off just flagging.

Comment: You'll get that reputation back if the question gets deleted (needs a recalc).